# MySQL How to rewrite View without variables

Tags: mysql, variables, view

I know MySQL doesn't allow vars in a View. I've tried to rewrite this View (break it down into separate queries) but can't get it right. Any ideas?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT  @r:= IF(@u = marketID, @r + 1,1) AS `Order`, @u:= marketID mktID,  betTime, betType, betPrice             
            FROM    tbl_data,
                    (SELECT @i:= 1) AS r,
                    (SELECT @u:= 0) AS u
            ORDER BY marketID, betTime ASC
        ) AS tbl_data
```

Here is some sample data:

| marketID | betTime | betType | betPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.197135542 | 2022-04-09 20:39:13 | draw_lay | 4.00 |
| 1.197135542 | 2022-04-09 20:39:28 | draw_lay | 4.02 |
| 1.197135542 | 2022-04-09 20:39:35 | draw_lay | 4.03 |
| 1.197135542 | 2022-04-09 20:42:35 | draw_lay | 4.04 |
| 1.197135542 | 2022-04-09 20:45:34 | draw_lay | 4.00 |
| 1.197188888 | 2022-04-09 20:47:40 | draw_lay | 4.06 |
| 1.197188888 | 2022-04-09 20:49:08 | draw_lay | 4.00 |
| 1.197188888 | 2022-04-09 20:51:06 | draw_lay | 3.95 |
| 1.197188888 | 2022-04-09 20:51:08 | draw_lay | 3.95 |
| 1.197188888 | 2022-04-09 20:51:21 | draw_lay | 3.95 |

MySQL version 8.0.22

Comment: Please add some sample data.

Comment: which mysql version you are using

Comment: Data added and MySQL version is 8.0.22

Comment: Describe the task completely (what does this query should do?). Provide sample data as online fiddle or as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Show desired output for this data with detailed explanations.

Comment: The query looks like common "enumerate rows in a group". If this is correct then common ROW_NUMBER() will solve.

Comment: Hi AKina, yes it adds an order by marketID ordered by the betTime. Any example of how to use ROW_NUMBER()?

Comment: I think this is it....   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY marketID ORDER BY betTime) AS RC FROM tbl_data ;

Comment: Thanks Akina, that was really very simple to do. I'd not used OVER(PARTITION .....) before.